# When is the HTML attribute backslash escaped as a JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, html

I noticed that backslash is escaped when I get "attribute value including backslash" with JavaScript in the following code.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("class")); // -> \A
console.log(document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("class").replace("\\A", "\A")); // -> A

console.log(document.getElementById("test").dataset.b); // -> \B
console.log(document.getElementById("test").dataset.b.replace("\\B", "\B")); // -> B
```

```html
<div id="test" class="\A" data-b="\B"></div>
```

---

The backslash is treated as a special character in JavaScript, and two backslashes (`\\`) represent one backslash (`\`).

The result of the above code means that when getting the attribute value with JavaScript using `getAttribute()`, one backslash (`\`) is escaped to two backslashes (`\\`) at somewhere.

However, in the [specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-element), it seems that the corresponding process is not applied.

---

#### Question

In which process of `getAttributes()` the backslash of HTML attribute is escaped (`\` -> `\\`)?

Comment: The `'\A'` in your `replace` is just an `'A'` because… reasons. To express one backslash in a string literal you need to type *two* backslashes. So, you replace the "A" with a backslash with an "A" without.

Comment: @deceze _To express one backslash in a string literal you need to type two backslashes._ > That's exactly what happens in JavaScript. However, I don't know when the backslash representation in JavaScript is applied to the attribute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between string literals (which require escaping) and string values from other places (like html, ajax, etc), which are what they look like. Only when converted to literals (ex: JSON.stringify, some console views, etc) do JS strings have backslash escaping. The escape is an output formatting artifact; internally, there are no escapes in the sequence of characters.

HTML doesn't need the same escaping on blackslashes, due to different roots of the standard. An attribute isn't "converted" to one with escaped backslashes unless it's formatted as a string literal. That would happen at a stage between the string and it's visible output. You can use alert() instead of console.log() to see the string as it really is. I believe that specifically for the console, the 
goal is to be more helpful to developers than accurate to the internals.

Comment: ... _unless it's formatted as a string literal_ > Why do backslash escapes not occur in "string literals" in "functions that return strings, such as the `getAttribute` method "? What the `getAttribute` method does is return a string. However, you can check that this return value is escaped in various ways other than `console` and `alert`.

Comment: functions that return strings don't (typically) return literals. literals are code, meant to be interpreted. the string content of an attrib is not meant to (or needed to) be interpreted.